# Warning: No available formula with the name "gcc". on mac(intel)

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, terminal, homebrew

[image: error message]

I want to use gcc compiler instead apple clang on my mac(intel).

But this error is shown..   " Warning: No available formula with the name "gcc" "

I did, 1. installed homebrew
2. brew install gcc

But this error is shown..   " Warning: No available formula with the name "gcc" "

Comment: what shows this error? What do you do to get this error? btw its not an error but a warning

Comment: Is it the `brew install gcc` command that shows the error? Or something else? Perhaps you need to specify a version number as well? Like `brew install gcc-12.2` or similar? What does the `brew` documentation tell you? What does the available tutorials for installing GCC with `brew` say?

Comment: I have edited the post, and attached the terminal screenshot. Would you please review it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone who gave feedback to this question.

Solution I have done:

1. running `brew doctor` , it recommended me to run three commands:

2.`rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"`

3. `brew tap homebrew/core`
4. and `git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master`
5. Then I run `brew install gcc` again.

Now it's working.